# Jquery Cycle Questions: Pause on load + Hover Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle

Hey Guys, building a site and I've got two questions for you. The site is hosted here for the time being: http://wesbos.com/tf/shutterflow/?cat=5 . 
 I have two questions:
1. Currently the slideshow rotates divs with the class of .slide that holds the image. inside it, a class of .cover overlays it with the data/ a semi-transparent background on over. 
 If you try this, it loads fine (due to the CSS display:none on .cover) but when I click a thumbnail it loads both divs, not applying display:none to the .cover div. It only fades out when I hover over. I am using Jquery Cycle and my code looks like this:(found in shutterflow.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:     'fade', 
next:   '#next', 
    pause: 1,
prev:   '#prev',
    pause:  '#pause',
    pager:  '.thumbs',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
                    var src = $('img',slide).attr('src');
                    return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + src + '"  height="75" /></a></li>';
            } 
});
```

And

```
        $(document).ready(      
              function() {
                $('.slide').hover(
                  function() {  $(".cover").fadeIn('500'); },
                  function () { $(".cover").fadeOut('500');
                 }  );
        }  );
```

How can I get .cover to load as display:none when a thumbnail is clicked?
2. My second question should be pretty easy. Looking at the snippet above, I want the slideshow to load in a paused state and to run only when the play link is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Added answer for first question.

First question:
Add the pagerClick option to the cycle function.

```
pagerClick:function(zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement) {$(slideElement).find('div.cover').hide();}
```

The second question seems easy:
based on the plugin [doc](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/int2.html):

Assuming you have a play/pause btn

btnPlayPause.toggle(function(){$("#slideshow").cycle('pause');},function(){$("#slideshow.cycle('resume');})

you can also change the play/pause button image in those functions.
Also look [here](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pause.html)

Comment: this pretty much did the trick, I used the pause code you gave on page load. The .cover hide worked as well but now they are showing on each transition (after each fade out). How do I hide a div after 500ms (aka let div fade out then hide it)?

Comment: I noticed a typo in your playpause code. resume is mis spelled.